# Can an rvalue be moved into a shared_ptr

Tags: c++, c++11, rvalue-reference

Is it possible to 'move' an `rvalue` into a `shared_ptr`. All the methods which I've tried so far result in a copy.

My desired usage pattern is:

```
class Element {
public:
    Element(const string &);
    Element(const Element &) = delete; //delete copy constructor
    // ...
};

class MyCollectionOfElements {
public:
    void add(Element &&); // add by rvalue
    // ...
protected:
    vector<shared_ptr<Element>> elements;
};

MyCollectionOfElements elements;
elements.add(Element("something"));
```

There are reasons why I want this pattern, and understand that there are alternative patterns which naturally work (e.g. passing the new `Element` as a pointer rather than an `rvalue`).

My current suspicion is that the incoming `rvalue` is on the stack, whilst I need to have it on the heap to store it in a `shared_ptr`, therefore a copy is inevitable.

Comment: There's no "stack" or "heap" in C++ (except for `std::stack` and `std::make_heap`).

Comment: I think he's referring to the program's [stack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Call_stack) and [heap](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management#HEAP), which absolutely do exist in C++

Comment: @Conduit: Citation needed for C++.

Comment: They're a staple of programming languages. When you allocate variables, pass them to functions, or do *literally anything with memory*, the data is stored in one of those two structures.

Comment: @Conduit: None of this has anything to do with C++.

Comment: [I'll just leave this here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) and be on my way.

Comment: @KerrekSB Would it perhaps be more correct to use the terms static memory vs dynamic memory?

Comment: @Default: Kind of. "Storage duration" is the most relevant concept in C++ in that direction. (It still doesn't have anything to do with this question.) "Scope" is also related and probably a lot more important.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yes:

```
void add(Element && e)
{
    elements.push_back(std::make_shared<Element>(std::move(e)));
}
```

You also have to make sure your class actually *has* a move constructor:

```
class Element
{
public:
    Element(Element &&) = default;
    // ...
};
```

By declaring a copy constructor, you inhibit the implicit declaration of a move constructor, so you need to declare it explicitly.

Comment: Thank you Kerrek. This doesn't work as I expected in Visual Studio. This won't compile unless I don't delete the copy constructor. When it has the copy constructor back, I can see that the memory address changes after the make_shared<Element>(std::move(e)), so `this` inside Element's lambda functions are still invalidated.

Comment: @ElliotWoods: Your question does not state that you have `this` pointers that should be unchanged -- you should clarify this in the question. It is probably not possible to avoid changing the `this` pointer (but that is another issue than move vs. copy).

Comment: @ElliotWoods: That's not what "moving" usually means. You can never "move" an actual variable. "Moving" always refers to moving a variable's *value*. The presented code is what you should want.

Comment: @KerrekSB - thank you. can you imagine why I might need to allow the copy constructor in Visual Studio for your method to work?

Comment: @ElliotWoods: I don't quite understand your question. Can you reduce the problem to its smallest possible form and post it as a separate question?

Comment: @KerrekSB : I've made a simple test of your solution at http://goo.gl/NIymiO which does work and compiles. Thank you. I had hoped it would mean `this` doesn't change, but that seems to be a separate issue as mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

Guess you misunderstand the idea of movement semantic. You have to pass pointer to smart pointer, and pointer can have any type - lvalue/rvalue

```
    void f(A *&&p) {}
```

function which accept rvalue ref to pointer which points to A; but p is still lvalue which has type r-value reference to a pointer, 
so u have to "cast"(std::move - does nothing just cast l-value to r-value)
std::shared_ptr(std::move(p));

```
    A *g() { return new A;}
    A *a;
    f(a);//error        
    f(g());//works fine
    f(new A());//also fine
```

Comment: Thank you jonezq, but the question is how (if possible) to create a `shared_ptr<Element>` from `Element &&` (not `Element * &&`), without causing a copy of the `Element`

Comment: You can take address of rvalue object and to pass it to shared_ptr<>, then you get out of function/method scope - object gets destroyed, and when shared_ptr decrements ref counter to zero will also call destructor of destroyed object (unexpected behavior).